# Meteor Collections (and Publishing) Confusion

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So I have a collection called Parties (I'm doing the angular-meteor tutorial). I've removed autopublish, and thus on the server, I've declared something like this:

```
Meteor.publish('parties', function () {
    return Parties.find({secret: false});
});
```

I've declared Parties in my 'both' directory, as `const Parties = new MongoObservable.Collection<Party>('parties');`

Now, lets say I have 3 documents in mongoDb, but one of which where secret is true. So, thinking about it, I would think that Parties would still return 3 documents when queried with `.find({})`. However, it only returns **2**. Why is this? I thought that Parties was just a global variable that would not be impacted by my publish declaration.

Comment: And just as a follow up, what does the 'parties' (the parameter that I pass into `new MongoObservable.collection`) mean? It doesn't seem have to mirror the name I give the collection in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parties is a variable which means two different things:

1. when on the server, it creates a reference to a mongo collection
2. when on the client, it creates a reference to minimongo and defines a collection inside it

when you publish, you specify a filtering criteria that indicates what data in the database will be published to minimongo on the client. the find() on the client references minimongo, i.e. the published data, and not the full database.

given your query, it is correct that the client sees 2 records.

edit:

this is a handy tool for your browser; it can show you what data has been published to the client.

https://atmospherejs.com/meteortoys/allthings

Comment: Just to clarify, if I check the number of documents on Parties on the server, it should show 3 while if I do the same thing on the client, it should show 2. And the reason for this is that meteor recognized that the Parties I reference on the client should be restricted because of my publish definition on the server?

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for that. I've been looking everywhere for an answer.